# React - what is the alternative for raised-button in raised-button?

Tags: reactjs

I need to add a button with github icon which can be done easily through RaisedButton in material-ui. But I have a beta version of material-ui and seems like it does not have raised-button. 
What is the alternative for this? Is there something similar in beta version of material UI? 
(Note: I cannot move to using v0.x of material-ui)

Answer (score 0):

Material UI beta has a raised button here: https://material-ui-next.com/demos/buttons/#raised-buttons

You need to specify the type with the variant prop like so:

```
import Button from 'material-ui/Button';

<Button variant="raised">
  Click Me
</Button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I wanted specifically to have a raised button with git icon like this
'''
    <RaisedButton
          href="https://github.com/callemall/material-ui"
          target="_blank"
          label="Github Link"
          secondary={true}
          style={styles.button}
          icon={<FontIcon className="muidocs-icon-custom-github" />}
        />
'''
I did try to see the example https://material-ui-next.com/demos/buttons/#raised-buttons. it uses the 'material-ui/Button' along with 'material-ui-icons' but did not see anything specific to git icon

Comment: I see. You can put any children inside of a button. Have you tried placing an img in it?
```<Button variant="raised">
  <img src='link to image'/>
</Button>```.